# Dropdown Menu with Jade and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, pug

I was wondering if someone could please let me know how dropdown menus are created within Jade while using Twitter Bootstrap. I currently have a menu that has the nav pills as stacked:

```
html  
  head  
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    include inc/header
  body
    h1.page-header= title
    ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked
    li#home: a(href='/') Home Page
    li#clear: a(href='/clear') Clear Blog Posts
    li#load: a(href='/load') Load Sample Posts
    li#list: a(href='/showContacts') Show Blog
    li#add: a(href='/add') Add Blog Post

   script.
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".active").removeClass("active");
       $("##{tab}").addClass("active");
     });

   block content
```

I have tried using .dropdown and .dropdown_toggle instead of .nav-stacked, however i am rather new to Jade and bootstrap so was unsure where to go from there and how i can create a dropdown menu?

Thanks

Comment: What version of bootstrap are u using?

Comment: Version 2, do i require version 3 for this?

Comment: Version 2, is okay. Where have you included the jQuery file? There was a bug i faced. Try adding the jquery file in the header as the first js file. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for twitter bootstrap version 2.3.2. I do not recommend you continuing with any older version of twitter.

```
!!! 5
html
head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/HOMEedit.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/bootstrap.css')
    include bootstrap/inc/scripts
body
    .dropdown
        a(href="#", data-toggle="dropdown").dropdown-toggle Dropdown trigger
        ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu', aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu')
            li
                a(href='#', tabindex='-1') Action
            li 
                a(href='#', tabindex='-1') Something else here
            li.divider
            li
                a(href='#', tabindex='-1') Separated link
    script.
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

In the above I use a separate file 'scripts' which i include in the jade docs.

they basically include

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='js/bootstrap.min.js') 
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js')
```

Please note that the order is important, and also the place in the header. It only worked for me when i included jQuery.js as top js file. I am sure that was not intended by the developers but its a bug or something.

Also note that i downloaded the bootstrap.min.js file from the 'customize' option http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html. which automatically compiles all .js and .css files into one to reduce the number of bootstrap files you then need to include separately.

Good Luck. ( I was a beginner not long ago, so hang in there, you'll get there)

Comment: Hi Sangram, thanks for the reply. Ive implemented that into my code however it appears to not be working. Ive added it to the body and all that shows up on the webpage is is "Dropdown trigger" and when i click it nothing occurs. Ive made sure that ive got jquery installed so the script should run, however it appears to not dropdown?

Comment: The above code is working. take note 1. that you are using bootstrap 2.3.2 and not an older version. and 2. that jQuery is the first library that is loaded to the jade file. is it?